# Event handling in WPF to add check boxes to Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf

I have  two combo Boxes in WPF application.

I have added checkboxes dynamically to the first Combo Boxes. 
If I select one of the check boxes from the first ComboBox, the checkbox event should be handled to add some checkboxes to the Second Combo Box.

I have tried, but I didn't work.

the code.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    AddAnalytes();
}


public void AddCartridges()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cartridges.Length; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
      //  cbox.Name = "cbox" + cartridges[i].ToString();
        cbox.Content = cartridges[i];
        this.CartridgeCombo.Items.Add(cbox);

        //CheckBox[] cartridgeBoxes= new
    }
}

public void AddAnalytes()
{
    if (this.CartridgeCombo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "CHEM8")
    {
        Analytes = new string[] { "NA", "K", "CL", "TCO2", "BUN", "CREA", "EGFR", "GLU", "CA", "ANG", "HCT", "HGB" };

        for (int i = 0; i < Analytes.Length; i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

            cb.Name = "cb" + Analytes[i];
            cb.Content = Analytes[i];
            this.AnalyteCombo.Items.Add(cb);
        }
    }
```

Comment: WinForms or WPF? Choose one, please.

Comment: Double confusion - Technology = WPF or WinForms?? Issue:- Handling CheckBox checked or Overlapping controls?? Rephrase the question.

Comment: @Prateek, It's WPF.

Comment: "I have tried, but I didn't work." - Can you be as descriptive as possible?

Comment: @John, added an event line this  cbox.Click+= new RoutedEventHandler(cbox_Checked);

Comment: @NagarajuKuricheti - What is the expected behavior when you check one/more checkboxes from first comboBox? If the behavior of each checkbox checked change is going to be different then there may not be a clean/reusable way of doing this. If the behavior is somewhat similar -- Create a generic method that defines the behavior and then attach that method to the cb.CheckedChange (or similar) event.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava, When I select any of the check boxes, no action was done. The application was idle.

Comment: @Nagaraju Did the event fire? Can you debug the handler?

Comment: @john, It didn't fire.

Comment: What does `cbox_Checked` do? Why do you expect it to call the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You have not used MVVM at all - so this will eventually get bit tricky for you - as everything is code behind. Below works for me:

```
private void PopulateCheckboxes1()
{
    for(int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
    {
        var chkBox = new CheckBox();
        chkBox.Content = string.Format($"TextBox: {idx}");
        chkBox.Tag = idx;
        chkBox.Checked += ChkBox_Checked;
        cmbBox1.Items.Add(chkBox);
    }
}

private void ChkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemsToAdd = (int)(sender as Control).Tag;
    cmbBox2.Items.Clear();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < itemsToAdd; idx++)
    {
        var chkBox = new CheckBox();
        chkBox.Content = string.Format($"TextBox: {idx}");
        cmbBox2.Items.Add(chkBox);
    }
}
```

Put your custom logic in ChkBox_Checked handler. My logic is to just add several check boxes to combo box 2 based on the Tag property.

Comment: Here I' getting the following Exception "object reference not setr to an instance".

Comment: Thats a Null Reference... @NagarajuKuricheti - Breakpoint at the line where it throws the exception and trace back how the initialization is happening.

Comment: Here "if (this.CartridgeCombo.SelectedItem == "CHEM8")". I'm getting that Exception